# Java & Excel: value being read wrong

Tags: java, excel, parsing, apache-poi

I am parsing data from an excel file and adding it to my data base using `HSSFCell` to parse the Excel file, I am using the following code to read the file

```
public void printCellDataToConsole(Vector dataHolder) throws SQLException {
            // this is for the rows in the file, set to one to skip the headings
            List<String> studentInformation = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
                    Vector cellStoreVector = (Vector) dataHolder.elementAt(i);
                    // this is for the colums in the table
                    for (int j = 0; j < cellStoreVector.size(); j++) {
                            HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
                            String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();
                            System.out.print(stringCellValue + "\t");                  
                    }
                    connectToDatabase.ammendTableInDatabase("INSERT INTO Student VALUES (" + cellStoreVector.get(0) + ",'" + cellStoreVector.get(1) + "','" + cellStoreVector.get(2) + "','" + cellStoreVector.get(3) + "','" + cellStoreVector.get(4) + "'," + cellStoreVector.get(5) + ",'" + cellStoreVector.get(6) + "')");
                    System.out.println();
            }
    }
```

Everything is working but when i try to read any value like the following

```
111223361
111223362
111223364
111223363
111223366
```

It reads them as the following

```
1.11223361E8
1.11223362E8
1.11223364E8
1.11223363E8
1.11223366E8
```

Why is this happening and how do i solve it?

Comment: Because I am also interesseted in reading values from Excel files, what framework do you use for doing that?

Comment: POI is my guess, since HSSFCell was mentioned.  I'd recommend Andy Khan's JExcel over POI.

Comment: @reporter: well i am using `poi-3.8-20120326.jar` to parse the excel files, do you want to know anything else?

Comment: @ duffymo : Does JExcel support new data format? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763624/jexcelapi-vs-apache-poi-which-is-better/4763930#4763930 mentions JExel cannot support  new version. (May be the answer need a tweek)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1.11223361E8` means `1.11223361 x (10 ^ 8)`, so `111223361 = 1.11223361E8`...

If you want to get it *well formatted*, use `Double.valueOf("1.11223361E8").longValue()`.

Comment: yes this solved the problem and thanks for explaining why the numbers where appearing in the format they where appearing in :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
cellValueLong = Long.valueOf(myCell.toString());
```

I faced the same problem myself a few weeks ago. This happens because the number you are extrating as a string, comes in scientific notation format. And since you get it as a string and not as a long/int/(whatever) it returns the string value of that number in that format.

Comment: I tried this but myCell.Value gives the following: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Value
  location: variable myCell of type org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell

Answer (score 0):

for getting values from excel sheet.this is the best solution.It may help u.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12067137/1211000