# Reading A excel Sheet in java . That excel sheet containing some bank cells as well

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
Date    Emp_Code    Emp_Name    Cardno  Shift_Start IN  OUT Shift_End   Status  Emp_Late    Left_Early  Hours_Worked    O T OS
26. Jan. 2011   001 KL Acharya  000001  9:00    9:15    18:34   18:00   P   0.15    0.00    9.19    0:00    0:34
26. Jan. 2011   002 Seemakiran Upadhya  000002  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   013 Sumana Ravishankar  000013  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   017 Gopalkrishna Prabhau KV 000017  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   021 Sarath Modali   000021  20:00   21:02   6:40    6:00    P   1.02    0.00    9.38    0:00    0:40
26. Jan. 2011   023 Siddharth Singh 000023  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   034 Meghana K   000034  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   036 Rajendra KS 000036  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   037 Rajesh K    000037  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   039 Mahesh PR   000039  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   041 Krishnamoorthy A    000041  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   047 Smruti Ranjan Panda 000047  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   049 Raghuraman K    000049  9:00    1:12        18:00   MS  0.00            0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   055 Raghavendra HS  000055  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   063 Anoop Chandran U    000063  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   069 Ramesh Kumar Hegde  000069  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   070 Mohan T 000070  9:00            18:00   A               0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   078 Shurabh Chaubey 000078  20:00   9:38    10:49   6:00    A   0.00    0.00    1.11    0:00    
26. Jan. 2011   079 Sourabha Mahopatra  000079  9:00            18:00   A               0:00
```

this is my excel sheet which containing some blank cells  in between. so i could nor read the sheet properly. Can any body give me a way to do it.so while reading row wise the column count decreses when it fins a blank cell in between.

Comment: Also is it true XLS or a csv?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is... Could you clarify what you want to happen for blank cells, do you want to skip them or count them? And what have you tried so far, and what didn't work?

Comment: It might help u


  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12067137/1211000

Answer (score 0):

To interact with Office Documents the only real solution is to use an API such as [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[APACHE POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) all the way

Answer (score 0):

Use poi-3.8!
This can deal blank cells !

```
 package com.vaadin.addon.tableimport;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ExcelImport implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8404407996727936498L;

    protected HSSFWorkbook workbook;

    /** The totals row. */
    protected Row titleRow, headerRow, totalsRow;
    protected Row hierarchicalTotalsRow;

    protected FileInputStream is = null;

    /**輔助存儲*/
    private List<List<Object>> data;
    private int headLineNum;

    public ExcelImport(File file, String dealString) {
        //獲得表頭行數
        headLineNum = reflex(dealString);
        //System.out.println("表頭行數 : " + headLineNum);

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HSSFSheet childSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        //System.out.println("有Physical行数" + childSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
        //System.out.println("有行数" + childSheet.getLastRowNum() + " , " +childSheet.getFirstRowNum());
        Object o;

        data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
        for (int aa = headLineNum; aa < childSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); aa++) {
            data.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
            for (int bb = 0; bb < childSheet.getRow(aa).getLastCellNum(); bb++) {
                data.get(aa-headLineNum).add(new String());
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < childSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); j++) {
            HSSFRow row = childSheet.getRow(j);
            //System.out.println("有Physical列数" + row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
            //System.out.println("有列数" + row.getLastCellNum());


            if (null != row) {
                for (int k = 0; k < row.getLastCellNum(); k++) {
                    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(k);

                    if (null != cell) {
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: // 数字
                            //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "   ");
                            //o = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            o = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // 字符串
                            //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "   ");
                            //o = String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            o =cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: // Boolean
                            //System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "   ");
                            //o = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            o =cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: // 公式
                            //System.out.print(cell.getCellFormula() + "   ");
                            //o = String.valueOf(cell.getCellFormula());
                            o =cell.getCellFormula();
                            break;
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: // 空值 -->Null Value
                            //System.out.println(" ");
                            o = " ";
                            break;
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR: // 故障
                            //System.out.println(" ");
                            o = " ";
                            break;
                        default:
                            //System.out.print("未知类型   ");
                            o = " ";
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //System.out.print("-   ");
                        o = "-   ";
                    }
                    if(j == headLineNum) {
                        data.get(j-headLineNum).set(k, getBottomStringById(dealString,k));
                    }
                    if(j >  headLineNum) {
                        data.get(j-headLineNum).set(k, o);
                    }

                }
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }

//      System.out.println("*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=*=");
//      for (List<Object> ll : data) {
//          for (Object ss : ll) {
//              System.err.print(String.valueOf(ss) + " , ");
//          }
//          System.err.println("*");
//      }
    }

    /**獲得表頭行數*/
    private int reflex(String dealString) {
        int rows = 1;
        TableHeadDeal thd = new TableHeadDeal(dealString);
        rows = thd.rows;
        return rows;
    }

    /**獲得表頭底部字串*/
    private String getBottomStringById(String dealString, int id) {
        String BottomStr = new String();
        TableHeadDeal thd = new TableHeadDeal(dealString);
        BottomStr = thd.getTableHeadBottomParams().get(id);
        return BottomStr;
    }

    public List<List<Object>> getListDate() {
        return data;
    }

}
```